# Detecting whether a click has been made to the left side or on the right side of div in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hey guys i have a div in react where i need to find out whether the click has been made to the left side or the right side of the div. Until now i was using jquery but i came to know its better to avoid jquery with react . So any solution to this without using jquery as i am pretty new to the react side?

This was what i was doing with the help of jquery

**HTML**

```html
<div onClick={()=>this.calcClick()}>....</div>
```

**JS**

```js
calcCLick = () => {
  var position = ""
  $("div").click(function (e) {
    var pWidth = $(this).innerWidth(); //use .outerWidth() if you want borders
    var pOffset = $(this).offset();
    var x = e.pageX - pOffset.left;
    // console.log(pWidth, pOffset, x);
    if (pWidth / 2 > x) {
      console.log("left");
      position = "left"

    }
    //  $(this).text('left');
    else {
      console.log("right");
      position = "right"
    }
  })
```

Comment: The function that handles your click assigns a click handler to every div in your DOM. I cannot see this working as expected at all. Anyway, you can get mouse coordinates and div dimensions using `e.clientX` and [`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, you can use the useRef hook of React itself and the getBoundClientRect().width to get the width of the div like said Chris in the comment above.

After this, you can get the mouse position in the div with the nativeEvent of the event.

[Check this sandbox if you want an example](https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-architecture-16if0?file=/src/App.js)